# Convert rows values into columns - oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm extracting some data from XML type of fields, getting some values from specific tags, and I managed to gather them in a form of such results:

```
echo  | type| color             | active
-------------------------------------------
echo1 | car | yellow,green,blue | no,no,no
echo1 | car | yellow,green      | yes,yes
echo2 | car | green,blue,red    | no,no,no
echo2 | car | blue,red          | yes,yes
echo3 | car | yellow,green      | no,yes
...
```

Now I need to convert those results into this:

```
echo  | type| color  | active
------------------------------
echo1 | car | yellow | no
echo1 | car | green  | no
echo1 | car | blue   | no
echo1 | car | yellow | yes
echo1 | car | green  | yes
echo2 | car | green  | no
echo2 | car | blue   | no
echo2 | car | red    | no
echo2 | car | blue   | yes
echo2 | car | red    | yes
echo3 | car | yellow | no
echo3 | car | green  | yes
...
```

meaning, I need to split values from the 3rd and 4th columns at once. Each of the values from color column has a corresponding value in the active column and I need to match those pairs in records.

So having such results I use this:

```
SELECT  echo, type, trim(x.COLUMN_VALUE) color, trim(y.COLUMN_VALUE) active 
FROM 
( RESULTS )
, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(color, ',', '","') || '"')) x, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(active, ',', '","') || '"')) y

ORDER BY echo, type, color, active
```

It works correctly if I convert only one of those two columns at once, but when I want to convert 2 at once, it multiplies the records, as if multiplying values from column y by values from column x.

If in the last column there were only "yes" or only "no" values, then it would work to use the distinct in the select, it would eliminate the obsolete (not true) records. But with mixed values I'm struggling to do it.

Can anyone give me a tip how to fix it to not get obsolete records?

Thanks in advance!

---

Sample XML:

```xml
<rowCollection>
  <row>
    <column name="active">YES</column>
    <column name="customertype">Default</column>
    <column name="type">Default</column>
    <column name="risklevel">Default</column>
    <column name="color">yellow</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="active">YES</column>
    <column name="customertype">Default</column>
    <column name="type">Default</column>
    <column name="risklevel">Default</column>
    <column name="color">green</column>
  </row>
</rowCollection>
```

Snippet of query used to generate results:

```
xmlcast(
  xmlquery(
    'string-join(/rowCollection/row/column[5]/text(),",")'
    passing xml_field
    RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS VARCHAR2(500)
) color,
xmlcast(
  xmlquery(
    'string-join(/rowCollection/row/column[1]/text(),",")'
    passing xml_field
    RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS VARCHAR2(300)
) active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause and use `INSTR` to iteratively find the delimiters and then `SUBSTR` to extract the values:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE results ( echo, type, color, active ) AS
SELECT 'echo1', 'car', 'yellow,green,blue', 'no,no,no' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'echo1', 'car', 'yellow,green',      'yes,yes'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'echo2', 'car', 'green,blue,red',    'no,no,no' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'echo2', 'car', 'blue,red',          'yes,yes'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'echo3', 'car', 'yellow,green',      'no,yes'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH lines ( echo, type, rn, idx, color, active, c_start, c_end, a_start, a_end ) AS (
  SELECT echo,
         type,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY echo, type, color, active ),
         1,
         color,
         active,
         1,
         INSTR(color,',',1),
         1,
         INSTR(active,',',1)
  FROM   results
UNION ALL
  SELECT echo,
         type,
         rn,
         idx + 1,
         color,
         active,
         c_end + 1,
         INSTR(color,',',c_end + 1),
         a_end + 1,
         INSTR(active,',',a_end + 1)
  FROM   lines
  WHERE  c_end > 0
  AND    a_end > 0
)
SELECT echo,
       type,
       CASE c_end
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( color, c_start )
       ELSE SUBSTR( color, c_start, c_end - c_start )
       END AS color,
       CASE a_end
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( active, a_start )
       ELSE SUBSTR( active, a_start, a_end - a_start )
       END AS active
FROM   lines
ORDER BY rn, idx
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ECHO  | TYPE | COLOR  | ACTIVE
> :---- | :--- | :----- | :-----
> echo1 | car  | yellow | yes   
> echo1 | car  | green  | yes   
> echo1 | car  | yellow | no    
> echo1 | car  | green  | no    
> echo1 | car  | blue   | no    
> echo2 | car  | blue   | yes   
> echo2 | car  | red    | yes   
> echo2 | car  | green  | no    
> echo2 | car  | blue   | no    
> echo2 | car  | red    | no    
> echo3 | car  | yellow | no    
> echo3 | car  | green  | yes
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f081a47d4509056c6cf6d894d0f41a3)*

---

**Update**

Don't aggregate and then split the delimited strings; just extract the values from the XML:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml_field ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<rowCollection>
  <row>
    <column name="active">YES</column>
    <column name="customertype">Default</column>
    <column name="type">Default</column>
    <column name="risklevel">Default</column>
    <column name="color">yellow</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="active">YES</column>
    <column name="customertype">Default</column>
    <column name="type">Default</column>
    <column name="risklevel">Default</column>
    <column name="color">green</column>
  </row>
</rowCollection>' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/rowCollection/row'
         PASSING t.xml_field
         COLUMNS
           active VARCHAR2(3) PATH '/row/column[@name="active"]',
           type   VARCHAR2(10) PATH '/row/column[@name="type"]',
           color  VARCHAR2(10) PATH '/row/column[@name="color"]'
       ) x;
```

**Output**:

There will be a way to generate the `echo` column; its just this isn't included in your sample data.

> ```
> ACTIVE | TYPE    | COLOR 
> :----- | :------ | :-----
> YES    | Default | yellow
> YES    | Default | green
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0277e401761c567a79e51498e3b0b538)*

Comment: Thanks! Works of course on my data. I added a portion of xml from which I extract my RESULTS. If you feel like it you can suggest another way to extract the tags values.

Comment: I didn't say it clearly, but the results are actually gathered from a few joined columns and I combine it to (echo, type, xml), so the echo and type columns are not part of the xml content.

Comment: Then just output the `echo` and `type` columns from the table(s) you've joined extract the other values from the XML.

Comment: Yup, all working now. I just couldn't figure out the syntax for extracting the XML values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hierarchy` query as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT ECHO, TYPE,
>   2      REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLOR, '[^,]+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE) AS COLOR,
>   3      REGEXP_SUBSTR(ACTIVE, '[^,]+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE) AS ACTIVE
>   4  FROM RESULTS
>   5      CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
>   6          SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL
>   7          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(COLOR, ',') + 1
>   8      ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) );
>
> ECHO  TYP COLOR      ACTIVE
> ----- --- ---------- --------------------------------
> echo1 car yellow     no
> echo1 car green      no
> echo1 car blue       no
> echo1 car yellow     yes
> echo1 car green      yes
> echo2 car green      no
> echo2 car blue       no
> echo2 car red        no
> echo2 car blue       yes
> echo2 car red        yes
> echo3 car yellow     no
> echo3 car green      yes
>
> 12 rows selected.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks! It works of course on my data, very elegant. It's just the cardinality and cost are much higher than the solution from MT0 above.